# How can I zoom to featureset geometry item

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I send GetFeatureInfo request to server with ajax and get the featureset data. I want to zoom a selected feature.

```
Object {type: "Feature", id: "mydata.39025", geometry: Object, geometry_name: "geom", properties: Object…}
```

Selected feature can be a **point**, **multilinestring**, **polygon**. So I can not cast it as an OpenLayers.Geometry.Point, or OpenLayers.Geometry.Polyline.

How can I zooom it?

Answer (score 1):

A late answer :-)

Every feature has an ol.geometry object, and an ol.geometry has an ol.Extent object, which is an array of numbers representing an extent: [minx, miny, maxx, maxy].

You can use this extent to calculate the center coordinate and to set the map->view center to this position. Afterwards you can calculate a resolution and set this to the view.